# Is C# suitable for a scripting language?

Tags: c#, scripting

I need a programming language to make tiny applications. As a C++ programmer, I think C++ is not practical for this purpose, because it takes too much effort to create a new application from scratch and to deploy it. However, I'd like to use a language equally powerful, so I was wondering whether C# can be used as a scripting language?

Comment: I agree with Thomas.  How can you expect people to take the time to answer your questions if you won't accept them.  I'll pass on this one.

Comment: Does that not kinda miss the point of SO though?

Comment: @RobV: I don't think so. I prefer the voting system over my own opinion to select the best answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Read this one

[CS-Script - The C# Script Engine](http://www.csscript.net/)

> CS-Script is a CLR (Common Language
>   Runtime) based scripting system which
>   uses ECMA-compliant C# as a
>   programming language. CS-Script
>   currently targets Microsoft
>   implementation of CLR (.NET
>   2.0/3.0/3.5) with limited support on Mono.
>
> CS-Script is an open-source initiative
>   that is distributed under the license
>   agreement, which can be found here.
>   However commercial support is also
>   available.
>
> CS-Script combines the power and
>   richness of C# and FCL with the
>   flexibility of a scripting system.
>   CS-Script can be useful for system and
>   network administrators, developers and
>   testers. For any one who needs an
>   automation for solving variety of
>   programming tasks.

and

[Treating C# Like A Scripting Language](http://www.mattephraim.com/blog/2009/01/02/treating-c-like-a-scripting-language/)

Comment: good answer. Right on the nail!

Answer (score 5):

I would say that the usual benefits of a scripting language are:

1. It normally has a command line interpreter
2. You don't necessarily have to compile it
3. It's easy to change the code - because the source file is the actual 'executable'

These are not features of C#, so a language that can do pretty much all that would be powershell, as it uses .net so it has access to all the features you might use in c#.

---

Edit: Just to resurrect this one from the dead...

Had a chat with a colleague, after thinking a bit about scripting languages that I have used like Ruby and Python.

One of the most important features for me in a scripting language is the ability to have code run directly in the script, without needing a main function. You don't do this in c#. However you do this in all the scripting languages that come to my mind:

eg, Ruby, Python, Javascript, Powershell

Comment: Mono provide a repl for C# (see link in my answer)

Comment: Starting in C# 9, you can use [Top-level statements (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/top-level-statements).

Answer (score 5):

You could try [Python](http://www.python.org/), which is both a very understandable and powerful language.
It is possible to parse/execute Python from many languages.

For example: Use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) to use C++ code in Python or [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/embedding.html#python.using_the_interpreter) to embed Python code in your C++ app.

Comment: Agreed. If the OP wants the strength of the .NET framework, IronPython is readily available.

Answer (score 4):

An other useful tool if you want to use C# for scripting is http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl : a C# interactive prompt from the mono team.

I'd say that Mono in particular provides all of the tools to use C# as a very effective scripting language, and nearly anything you write in will run fine in .net if thats your main target environment.